# Rails 3.2 update attribute after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, after-save

I want to update an specific attribut in my database after save data.

For example i have an column in my table which called pending and it's an boolean. i want to set this value to true when data was saved.

```
after_save :do_something

private
def do_something
  self.update_column(:pending, true)
end
```

This doesn't work. Anyone here who has an solution?

Comment: why don't you try before_save?

Comment: This alos doesn't worked

Comment: just write self.pending = true in it.

Comment: you need to add attr_accessor :pending to model.

Comment: This works fine when i use before_save. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your attribute directly like:

```
after_save { |user| user.username = user.username.downcase }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try after_commit instead of after_save. It will operate outside of the save transaction.